# Normalizing the covariance matrices of a series of random vectors

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, normalization, covariance-matrix

Assume I have a  $3$-dimensional series
$\{\boldsymbol{v}_{t}\}$, where
$\boldsymbol{v}_{t} = (x_{t}, y_{t}, z_{t})$. Then the covariance
matrix of $\boldsymbol{v}_{t}$ is:
\begin{equation*}
  \Sigma_{t}^{} = \boldsymbol{v}_{t}^{}\boldsymbol{v}_{t}^{T} =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \sigma_{x}^{2} & \rho\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y} & \rho\sigma_{x}\sigma_{z}\\
    \rho\sigma_{y}\sigma_{x} & \sigma_{y}^{2} & \rho\sigma_{y}\sigma_{z}\\
    \rho\sigma_{z}\sigma_{x} & \rho\sigma_{z}\sigma_{y}&\sigma_{z}^{2}
  \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation*}
(correlation is constant for simplicity also I dropped the $t$ subscripts).

If  I wanted to normalize the
covariance matrix to get the correlation matrix, I would calculate
\begin{equation*}
  D^{-1}_{t}\Sigma_{t}^{} D^{-1}_{t} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \rho& \rho\\
    \rho & 1 & \rho\\
    \rho & \rho&1
  \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation*}
where $D_{t} = \sqrt{\mathrm{diag}(\Sigma_{t})}$.

Now my question is, could I also normalize the one dimensional
series$\{x_{t}\}$, $\{y_{t}\}$ and $\{z_{t}\}$ individually first, to then get to the correlation matrix by simply calculating $\boldsymbol{v}_{t}^{}\boldsymbol{v}_{t}^{T}$ ?

Comment: If the equivalence of these two formulas isn't perfectly clear, why not carry out both calculations and compare?  The correct answer depends on your assumptions about the series and what you mean by normalize: most of what you write is correct only when one assumes all three series have zero means.

Comment: Yes all three series have a mean of zero, and by normalizing I mean dividing each series by its standard deviation.